# ElasticSearch [Search by term] can find result but [Get by document ID] cannot

Tags: elasticsearch

From my understanding, both _search and _doc command can return the same result with the same id.
However, I just encountered a very strange issue: the search by term (_id=1) can find the result while /doc/1 cannot...

when I use the get command: GET /my_index/_doc/1, it returns:

```
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "found": false
}
```

But when I use the search:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  }
}
```

It does returns:

```
  {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": "xxx"
     }
}
```

Both uses the same _id field to match the same index, but the first cannot find, the second get the result.
(the index doesn't have replication)

Comment: this is pretty strange, hope you are using the same index name in both the request

Comment: yes, i double confirmed that...